# I changed columns names, but SAS PROC REPORT still uses the old names

Tags: sas, ods, proc-report

Using PROC SQL, I changes column names from English to Hebrew.
When I use such tables via PROC REPORT, SAS uses the English columns names, even though the BY and DEFINE statements use the new Hebrew named column

```
PROC  REPORT DATA= work.sharon ;
BY 'סניף'n ;
DEFINE 'סניף'n / group;
RUN;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing that the original data had labels.  SAS will keep the old labels after you rename a variable.  You can see the problem here:

```
data blah;
    i = 23;
    label i = "eye";
run;

data blah2;
    set blah (rename = (i = a));
run;

proc report data = blah2;
run;
```

You can manually set the label for each variable with a `label` or `attrib` statement or, if you prefer to always use the variable names, just strip off all the labels for the dataset like this:

```
data blah3;
    set blah2;
    * remove all labels;
    attrib _all_ label = " ";
run;

proc report data = blah3;
run;
```

Answer (score 1):

If a variable has a LABEL PROC REPORT will use it as the column header.  You can change the label or override in the define statement or use the SAS system option NOLABEL;
Try one of these

```
label 'סניף'n = 'סניף';

DEFINE 'סניף'n / group 'סניף';

options label=0;
```

Comment: To prevent label typos, you can temporarily clear a variable's label, in which case the variable name is used as the default label.  `label 'סניף'n = ' ';` (make sure there is one space in the label value)

Comment: And `DEFINE 'סניף'n / group "";` works too. (make sure there is no space between the double qutation)